# Store hashmap in storage or in db?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, hashmap

I have a hashmap string to string, and I would like this hashmap to be saved in memory so that it can be reused later in time 
The main factor I use a hashmap for is the O(1) access parameter 
As I modify the hashmap very often, I don't think I should serialize / de serialize everything to add values. 
Another option is database. But do I lose my performance of O(1)?

Looking for suggestions / code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you select by primary key the primary key has an index on it. Usually a B-Tree so the complexity should be O(log(n)) being n the number of rows of the table. Off course there is more thing to it like disk access, query caching etc